# ORACLE - How to count the total of two queries(with different WHERE clauses) from same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to capture the aggregate of each number but am not sure how to gather all the results from a couple of queries(All data from the same table) that have different 'WHERE' criteria.

For example,

1st query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF')
AND tbl.send_date > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
GROUP BY tbl.job_nbr;
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.from IN ('GGGB','GVCE','GMWA','GTYR')
AND tbl.to IN ('GGGBP2','GVCEP3','GMWAP1','GTYRP3')
AND tbl.send_date > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
GROUP BY tbl.job_nbr;
```

I'm not sure if just using a WHERE clause satisfy my requirement

```
WHERE tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF')
AND tbl.from IN ('GGGB','GVCE','GMWA','GTYR')
AND tbl.to IN ('GGGBP2','GVCEP3','GMWAP1','GTYRP3')
```

Where I get confused is that results that are produced by my 1st query don't need to meet the 1st AND operator condition of the 2nd query. It seems if I incorporate all of my listed values in the 'tbl.from IN' condition and use the AND operator('tbl.to IN') that the returned results will only be those listed in the 'tbl.from IN' condition with the 'tbl.to IN' column.

Both queries produce separate results obviously, but I want to combine set of results so that I can count all occurrences, GROUP'ed BY unique job number(tbl.job_nbr).

*Note: I'm a little concerned about performance as well, because I want to incorporated in a larger query.

I'm sure its something simple, or at least somewhat simple, but I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out. If anyone would be kind enough help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

If I did not explain clearly enough or anyone has additional questions, I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT tbl.job_nbr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF')
               THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as cnt1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.from IN ('GGGB', 'GVCE', 'GMWA', 'GTYR') AND 
AND tbl.to IN ('GGGBP2', 'GVCEP3', 'GMWAP1', 'GTYRP3')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as cnt2
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF')
AND tbl.send_date > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
GROUP BY tbl.job_nbr;
```

Comment: Thanks! Would I be able to add those two case aliases together?

Comment: You can use a subquery to add the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

use  `case when`, i mean conditional aggregation:

```
 select tbl.job_nbr, 
  sum(case when tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF') then 1 else 0 end) 
as firstquery_count,
  sum(case when tbl.to IN ('GGGBP2','GVCEP3','GMWAP1','GTYRP3' then 1 else 0 end) 
 as secondndtquery_count
 from tbl where tbl.send_date > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  group by tbl.job_nbr
```

from comments it seems you want add both count so you can use cte

```
with cte as
(
select tbl.job_nbr, 
      sum(case when tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF') then 1 else 0 end) 
    as firstquery_count,
      sum(case when tbl.to IN ('GGGBP2','GVCEP3','GMWAP1','GTYRP3' then 1 else 0 end) 
     as secondndtquery_count
     from tbl where tbl.send_date > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
      group by tbl.job_nbr
) select job_nbr,firstquery_count+secondndtquery_count as total
   from cte
```

but with using cte you could do the same with 1st query just by using addition of that two count

Comment: Thanks! Would I be able to add those two case aliases together?

Comment: @ADOT together means?

Comment: SUM firstquery_count and secondquery_count

Comment: @ADOT yes you can

Comment: @ADOT answer eidted

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need 1 counter, so combine the conditions with `OR`:

```
SELECT tbl.job_nbr, COUNT(*) counter FROM tbl 
WHERE 
  tbl.send_date > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND 
  (
    tbl.from IN ('NIVA', 'TIRB', 'RIFG', 'PWDF')
    OR ( 
      tbl.from IN ('GGGB','GVCE','GMWA','GTYR')
      AND 
      tbl.to IN ('GGGBP2','GVCEP3','GMWAP1','GTYRP3')
    )
  )
GROUP BY tbl.job_nbr;
```

Comment: This actually meets my exact requirement. Thank You! I knew the logic in the WHERE clause was simple. Now if I can get it to run a little faster(No privileges to create index or view)

Comment: These `IN (...)` statements are known for their inefficiency, but I can't see how you can avoid them

Comment: From https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/short-circuit-evaluation-in-plsql, **maybe** puting the date condition first would improve performance. I will edit